# C++ Text-Based RPG Problem With My Inventory System

Tags: c++

Im starting a project with some friends and we have this problem in our inventory system. We're a bit new in c++ and we've been trying to understand the mistake for a little while but still cant find the problem thx in advance.
The probleme seems to be when I used vector.
For some reason once vector is used I get syntax error in the Inventory part and Equip Part.
Sorry if theres grammar error english is'nt my first language

```
// inventorySysteme.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct Item{
    string name;   // le nom
    string purpose;   // weapon, armor
    int stats;     // Dammage, armor point
    int attribute; // 0 = rien  1 = armor pearcing  2 = magic dammage ECt.....
};

int main()
{
    Item Sword{
        "RustedSword", // nom 
        "Weapon",       // weapon
        10,      // 10 de dammage
        1        // armor pearcing
    };
    Item Staff{
        "FirerStaff",
        "Weapon",
        20,
        2
    };

    string input; // What the player insert
    vector<string> Equipment = { "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", }; // If the place is free
    string InventorySlots[] = { "Weapon", "Weapon", "Objec1", "Object2", "Object3" }; // Nom et place inventaire
    vector<Item> Inventory = { Sword, Staff };  // inventaire

    while (true) {
        cin >> input;
        if (input == "equipment") {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                cout << InventorySlots[i];
                if (Equipment[i] == "Empty") {
                    cout << " " << Equipment[i] << "\n\n";
                }
            }
        }
// Equip Part
        if (input == "equip") {
            cout << "What would you like to equip?\n";
            cin >> input;
            for (int i = 0; i < Inventory.size(); i++) {
                //Search for item player want to equip and equip it in the right place.
                if (input == Inventory[i].name) {
                    Equipment[Inventory[i].purpose] = Inventory[i].name;
                    cout << "Successfully equiped!" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
// Inventory Part
        if (input == "inventory") {
            for (int i = 0; i < Inventory.size(); i++) {
                cout << "________________________________________" << endl;
                cout << "|  " << Inventory[i] << endl;
                cout << "|  Carried items " << Inventory.size() << " / " << 10 << endl;
                cout << "|_______________________________________" << endl;
            }
        }
        if (input == "quit") {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about an error message that you are having trouble understanding?  [I see a few errors in this code](https://godbolt.org/z/dhE5xhvb6), but you don't seem to mention any of them.

Comment: Well when in the equip part of the code all my [] are'nt getting read for some reason sorry im new here still trying to understand and get better for the question

Comment: `Equipment[Inventory[i].purpose] = Inventory[i].name;` You can't use a string as an array index, consider an `enum` instead. `cout << "|  " << Inventory[i] << endl;` For this you'll either need to create an `operator<<` for `Item` or print the members individually. You probably want to print the first line before the loop and the last 2 lines after the loop.